# AIR iOS dysm/symbolicate file

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, air, symbolicatecrash

Submitted an app to the iOS store yesterday and they threw me back some crash logs that happened on launch. All the shiny numbers in the log apparently mean something, but I can't find out how to translate them. According to old forum posts, I need a [dysm](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/995571) or a [symbolicate link](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1202883) file. However, the references that point to the [solution](http://blogs.adobe.com/rajorshi/2011/11/18/debugging-native-extensions-for-air-ios/) seem to be expired. Looking throug the .ipa in Winrar, I see my strings files, extensions, icons and the like, but nothing that I can see relates to a .dysm. Where would I find this? To have it work fine in debug with a dev provision/certificate and then have it not with a iTunes release prov/cert leads me to believe it may be related to that, but I only had one testing device at the time so I am a bit worried.

Side Question: I was unable to install the ipa when I changed it from dev to release. This is normal though, since it doesn't have the testing device's uid in the provision, correct?

Answer (score 1):

you can find .dysm: 
open your app in xcode -> open products -> right click and show in finder(.app) 
or 
you must operate in computer which you archived.

Comment: Thanks. I made the ipa using Animate on Windows but I have a macbook at work. I would be able to open the ipa in xcode after I moved it, right?

Comment: no! you cant find it in other computer! you can only find it in local computer which you archived!  and you also cant find it if that dont generate .dysm when you archive.

Comment: This, unfortunately, doesn't answer my specific question then. A good answer though. I don't use Xcode and I run on Windows with Animate so I am at a roadblock here.

Answer (score 1):

I use Animate on Mac and the .dysm file is automatically produced when the .ipa is produced.

Typically a .dysm file is used along with the crash reports to isolate the symbol/object/function that has caused the crash. But it the case of AIR app this isn't workable.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1693126

To test your app before submitting to the App Store for approval you should upload it to TestFlight. This allows you to test a distribution build.

For you TestFlight compatible build you need to add a couple of nodes to you app-descriptor file.

```
<Entitlements>
<![CDATA[ <key>get-task-allow</key>
<false/>
<key>beta-reports-active</key>
<true/> ]]>
</Entitlements>
```

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1652215

If your TestFlight app crashes you can access the device logs via Xcode to see what happened. Or build in some kind of trace output textfield into your app where you can output what is happening as your app loads. Similar to how you would use trace() in debug mode.